# jquery not hiding classes and animating in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

My goal is to create a page where every time I click a new line of text animates and fades in. To do that I first hide the elements "fadeDown1" through "fadeDown 4", then animate each "fadeDownN" element once per n each time when "downArrow" is clicked.

The problem is that in order to do that, I need to hide the elements in the first place before I can fade them in.  The first problem is that they're not hiding.  The second problem is that the animation doesn't seem to fire.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <p class="fadeDown1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at interdum dui. Nullam blandit est libero. Maecenas a ex ante. Donec mollis eleifend nunc quis sagittis. 
        </p>

        <p class="fadeDown2">

            Nullam eu lacus sed neque feugiat vulputate. Sed finibus et nulla at mollis. Sed ultricies eu massa vitae suscipit. Fusce a semper est. Nunc sed egestas lectus.


            </p>
        <p class="fadeDown3">

            Nam scelerisque condimentum sapien, ut semper turpis pretium ac. Vivamus pulvinar finibus nulla, nec sollicitudin purus laoreet vel. In finibus, elit nec lacinia pulvinar, tortor est pretium justo, 

            </p>

        <p class="fadeDown4">
             Donec consequat massa vitae massa viverra, nec pellentesque lectus dictum. Curabitur vitae nisi in nunc vestibulum mattis. 

        </p>

        <p class="fadeDown5">
            Pellentesque egestas venenatis suscipit. Integer dui lacus, luctus sed sem nec, volutpat vulputate lacus. 
        </p>

        <div class="downArrow"> 
            <p>&darr;</p>
            </div>

    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/introclick.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Script Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

var i = 1; 
var j = 1;

//Hide the fadeDown elements on page load
    $(".downArrow").append("</p> Test </p>");


    function hideThemAll(){

        for (i=1; i < 6 ; i++){
        if (hiddenVars = 1){
            $("fadeDown"+i).hide();
        }
    }
}

hideThemAll();


//click arrow to simultaneously fade in and animate down one "fadeDown" class per click 
//(so no for loop)


    $(".downArrow").on("click",() => {

        $("fadeDown"+j).fadeIn({queue: false, duration:'slow'});
        $("fadeDown"+j).animate({top: "-10px"}, 'slow');
        j++;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is `Hide()` shouldn't it be `hide()` ? JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I swapped the case.  The issue seems to still persist unfortunately

Comment: Also, the css selector for ID is `#someID`. You're missing the `#` character in all of your selectors.

Comment: Oh, actually, you're trying to create a css selector for class, you need a `.` character at the start not a `#` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is begging for a CSS animation solution...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.fadeDown:hover {animation: AnimText 2s linear 0s infinite alternate none;}

@keyframes AnimText {
   0% {opacity:1;}
  50% {opacity:0.5;}
 100% {opacity:0;}
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<p class="fadeDown">Some demo text...</p>

<p class="fadeDown">Another line...</p>

<p class="fadeDown">Yet another...</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good thinking, but with my code I'd like to click on the the arrow that isn't the animation text itself to trigger the animation on the text, which from what I've been researching isn't something that pure CSS can do.

Comment: You are right. The only way you are going to change based on a click event is with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Jeez-

I wasn't using the . selector for class in my JavaScript to select the classes.  Issue solved!  Don't forget your syntax, everyone!